# How do I combine a date and CSV filter to get the correct @timestamp field?

Tags: timestamp, logstash

I have a log file in txt format and I concluded after various hair-pulling attempts it was easiest and cleanest to use a csv filter ( I have experimented with grok patterns and it was messy).
One line from my log file looks like this.... ( 5 fields with the first being date time) 
18/MAR/2015:15:00:02, Accept, Apple-1, 60649, 10.31.5.8

What I want is for logstash to read this, take the first field which is the date time and assign that to the @timestamp field and proceed with parsing the remaining 4 fields using a CSV filter.

My code for this is pasted below ....

```
input {
    stdin{}
}

filter {

date {
        locale => "en"
        match => ["message", "dd/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss,"]
        timezone => "Europe/London"
        target => "@timestamp"
       # add_field => { "debug" => "timestampmatched"}
   }

csv {
         columns => ["@timestamp", "Decision", "Service", "PortNumber", "SourceIP"]
        separator => ","
    }

}

output {
    elasticsearch {
       #action => "index"
        host => "localhost"
        }
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
     }
```

Please note that I tested the date filter separately to ensure that it works and it does.
The trouble is, when I run this and paste the log line in the prompt (because it's stdin) I get the following error...

```
Using milestone 2 filter plugin 'csv'. This plugin should be stable, but if you see strange behavior, please let us know! For more information on plugin milestones, see http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/plugin-milestones {:level=>:warn}
18/MAR/2015:15:00:02, Accept, Apple-1, 60649, 10.31.5.8
Failed parsing date from field {:field=>"message", :value=>"18/MAR/2015:15:00:02, Accept, Apple-1, 60649, 10.31.5.8", :exception=>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "18/MAR/2015:15:00:02, Accept, Apple-1, 60649, 10.31.5.8" is malformed at " Accept, Apple-1, 60649, 10.31.5.8", :level=>:warn}
Trouble parsing csv {:source=>"message", :raw=>"18/MAR/2015:15:00:02, Accept, Apple-1, 60649, 10.31.5.8", :exception=>#<TypeError: The field '@timestamp' must be a Time, not a String (18/MAR/2015:15:00:02)>, :level=>:warn}
{
       "message" => [
        [0] "18/MAR/2015:15:00:02, Accept, Apple-1, 60649, 10.31.5.8"
    ],
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2015-05-01T12:59:13.011Z",
          "host" => "UOD-220076",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "_csvparsefailure"
    ]
}
```

I don't understand the error.  I therefore decided to try something different with the code below....

```
input {

 stdin{}
}

filter {

date {
        locale => "en"
        match => ["message", "dd/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss,"]
        timezone => "Europe/London"
        target => "@timestamp"
        add_field => { "debug" => "timestampmatched"}
   }

csv {
         columns => ["timestampmatched", "Decision", "Service", "PortNumber", "SourceIP"]
        separator => ","
    }

}

output {
    elasticsearch {
       #action => "index"
        host => "localhost"
        }
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
     }
```

The only difference between this code and the first code is two additions, a field called 'timestampmatched' and having the first column in the csv filter being 'timestampmatched' (as opposed to @timestamp). I then get the following result...

```
UOD-220076:bin student$ logstash -f fwlogs1.conf
Using milestone 2 filter plugin 'csv'. This plugin should be stable, but if you see strange behavior, please let us know! For more information on plugin milestones, see http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/plugin-milestones {:level=>:warn}
18/MAR/2015:15:00:02, Accept, Apple-1, 60649, 10.31.5.8
Failed parsing date from field {:field=>"message", :value=>"18/MAR/2015:15:00:02, Accept, Apple-1, 60649, 10.31.5.8", :exception=>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "18/MAR/2015:15:00:02, Accept, Apple-1, 60649, 10.31.5.8" is malformed at " Accept, Apple-1, 60649, 10.31.5.8", :level=>:warn}
{
             "message" => [
        [0] "18/MAR/2015:15:00:02, Accept, Apple-1, 60649, 10.31.5.8"
    ],
            "@version" => "1",
          "@timestamp" => "2015-05-01T13:11:04.399Z",
                "host" => "UOD-220076",
    "timestampmatched" => "18/MAR/2015:15:00:02",
            "Decision" => " Accept",
             "Service" => " Apple-1",
          "PortNumber" => " 60649",
            "SourceIP" => " 10.31.5.8"
}
```

...... which is what I want EXCEPT, that the @timestamp field should be "timestampmatched".

Any ideas, please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the `csv` filter first like this:

```
csv {
  columns => ["timestamp", "Decision", "Service", "PortNumber", "SourceIP"]
  separator => ","
}
```

Followed by the Date filter on the `timestamp` field created above

```
date {
    locale => "en"
    match => ["timestamp", "dd/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss"]
    timezone => "Europe/London"
}
```

That should work for you.  Logstash applies the filters in order.